# Cannot import @tensorflow/tfjs-node in nodejs

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

Cannot import @tensorflow/tfjs-node into my program.
I was trying to import it as follows:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
```

And received an error as follows:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/nama/working/Canvas-WEB/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v4/tfjs_binding.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nama/working/Canvas-WEB/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js:44:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

But when i try to import @tensorflow/tfjs as

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs')
```

No error was encountered.

I installed @tensorflow/tfjs-node using npm as

```
sudo npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

Then got an output (follows):

````
@tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.7 install /home/nama/working/Canvas-WEB/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node


node scripts/install.js

CPU-linux-1.2.7.tar.gz
(node:29606) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/nama/working/Canvas-WEB/node_modules/@tens
orflow/tfjs-node/deps'
(node:29606) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:29606) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not h
andled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
npm WARN canvas-web@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.7
updated 1 package and audited 276 packages in 12.428s
found 0 vulnerabilities```
````

Comment: @Thomas Dondorf , thank you for your support it worked !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here.

**Installation of the package as root**

You want to install the dependencies as root but npm will not run as root by default. Pass [the following arguments](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm) to enable root privileges:

```
sudo npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

You should also reconsider using another (not root) to run your script.

**Tensorflow.js require**

The require of `tensorflow/tfjs-node` will not work the way you do it, the package `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` will not export anything and is only required to use the native C++ bindings.

Here is how it should be done (quote from the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup#nodejs_setup)):

```js
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

Comment: Tried the same does not works for me, so i created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442632/error-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-c-program-files-nodejs-tf-n

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by running the command below at `node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node`

```
$ cd node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/
$ npm install
> @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.6 install /Users/tomoima525/workspace/javascript/tensorflow/baseball/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
> node scripts/install.js

CPU-darwin-1.2.7.tar.gz
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
```

Also you might want to try with 1.2.6 of tfjs-node, which I was able to work.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node#mac-os-x-requires-xcode

Comment: thank you @tomoima525 for your support , my issue was resolved .

Comment: landed here because pnpm wasn't working for me, running `pnpm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node` worked for me. Thanks @tomoima525